# how to load the license for validation using portable.Licensing

Tags: validation, load, licensing, portability

I have generated a "license.lic" file using Portable.Licensing. I'm unable to load it. How to load and validate the license using Portable.Licensing.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://dev.nauck-it.de/projects/portable-licensing/wiki/GettingStarted) for loading a license file and validating shows:

The easiest way to assert the license is in the entry point of your application.
First load the license from a file or resource:

> var license = License.Load(...);

Then you can assert the license:

> using Portable.Licensing.Validation; var validationFailures =
>   license.Validate()
>                                       .ExpirationDate()
>                                           .When(lic => lic.Type == LicenseType.Trial)
>                                       .And()
>                                       .Signature(publicKey)
>                                       .AssertValidLicense();

Portable.Licesing will not throw any Exception and just return an enumeration of validation failures.
Now you can iterate over possible validation failures:

> foreach (var failure in validationFailures)
>            Console.WriteLine(failure.GetType().Name + ": " + failure.Message + " - " + failure.HowToResolve);

Comment: the document isn't clear enough. at first glance i tried file name as parameter of `Load`, after some xml exceptions I began to think it might need file content.